# Why is this rspec test for a rake task green if I put expect before the invoke?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rspec

Here's rake task that's using threads to email async...Why is this rspec test for a rake task green if I put expect before the invoke?  And is it appropriate to put the "expect" before "subject.invoke"?

**rspec test**

```
describe 'send foxes' do

subject { rake['send_foxes'] }

before do
   allow(SomeMailer).to receive_message_chain(:send_free_fox, :deliver_now)
end

it "should send fox" do
   expect(SomeMailer).to receive(:send_free_fox)
   subject.invoke
end
end
```

**rake task**

```
task :send_foxes do
    foxObject.find_in_batches(batch_size: 600) do |foxes|
      batch = Proc.new do
        fox_it(foxes)
      end
      Thread.new { batch.call }
    end
  end

  private
    def fox_it(foxes)
      foxes.each do |fox|
        if fox.status == 'kitten'
          user = User.find_by(id: fox.user_id)
          SomeMailer.send_free_fox(user: user).deliver_now
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling expect to `receive` on the `SomeMailer` here is creating ang an expectation on the the `SomeMailer` object that the `send_free_box` method is called within the test, the test would fail if the `SomeMailer` did not get the `send_free_box` method called.

If `SomeMailer` a mock, or the actual Mailer Object. In this scenario, if `SomeMailer` is a mock, then adding the expectation like this is fine, although you should also check the correct the arguments are passed in too, as well as return a correct mock for calling `deliver` on. Otherwise, if the `SomeMailer` is a real mailer, then you should test that emails are added to the mail queue correctly and not not touch the mail system at all.

Also, I'd recommend not using threads here, they make the code much harder to debug, introduce race conditions (especially when testing) and don't  provide much performance increase.

Comment: what if I was batching through hundreds of thousands or millions of records at 10,000 at a time - should I use threads then?

Comment: If your expecting that kind of throughput, then you'd do well to investigate systems that provide better concurrency such as swift or go. Or looking at a hosted solution

Answer (score 1):

When using `receive` you always need to call expect before the code under test is run.

`expect(foo).to receive(:bar)` tells rspec to intercept and record the indicated method calls. If you do this after calling invoke then while invoke was running it will have been calling the original implementation of the method and rspec will not know whether it was called or not.

As you imply, this is different from other uses of `expect` which verify straightaway that some condition holds. With `receive` the verification phase is done after the example has run.